# Find center point in polygon includes point Java

Tags: java, gps

I have a problem. I have an array tag that includes the outline of a polygon, each point has gps coordinates.

I would like to find the focus point is in my array.

How can I do that?

I would like to have a gps coordinates of a red point (just one no matter).
[image]

Edit:
I have a area, i want center my zoom in a map at the middle of this area. This area is represented by a polygon of point. I want the coordinates of this point.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'focus point'? The intersection of the upper right and lower left corner points? Or the 'center of gravity' point or whatever you can calculate here?

Comment: I *think* the asker wants to know whether a given point (probably focused by the user or something) is on the line described by his array (the outline of the polygon). But yeah, please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I mean the point the most center vertically. My arrayList have multiple point object. A point have a latitude and a longitude. In would like to find the point the most center vertically. It's understandable or not? Thanks and sorry for my english....

Comment: 'the point the most center vertically'... wow. Could you please give us an example to improve our understanding? What is your intention behind the question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a area, i want center my zoom in a map at the middle of this area. This area is represented by a polygon of point. I want the coordinates of this point.

Comment: Please copy your last comment to the question, this will heavily improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through your points and remember the smallest and greatest x, y coordinate. After that your x-coordinate is `xcenter = (xmax-xmin)/2` and `ycenter = (ymax-ymin)/2`. That's the geometrical center.

If you want the 'Centroid of polygon' you can take the formula discussed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon (it's a sumformula over the coordinates).

[image]

Comment: How find the point in my arraylist, who is the closest of centroid?

Comment: Loop through all your points and calculate the distance between each and the centroid. Remember the smallest distance and the corresponding point. The formula for distance between points is something like `r=sqrt (deltaX^2+deltaY^2)`.

Comment: nvm. I was thinking of two's complement, no idea how I confused them.